# celery task is not working on prod server

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/virtualenvs/myProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/virtualenvs/myProj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/myProj/myProj/apps/myProj/tasks.py", line 43, in get_somestuff
    str_response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 520, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 445, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 379, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 528, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

when I run task in prod server, locally it is working perfectly.

the bit is

```
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

what may I be missing? the url I am reading is available thru browser

Comment: On the server try to fetch the same URL using [wget](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm), If it does not succeed then probably the website you are trying to fetch has blocked your production server IP.

Comment: There is a very high probability that the worker threads don't have enough permissions. Also high probability that the logs are not being written due to insufficient permissions.